# Formatting multiple lines of PYsnmp 4.4 print output to rows and columns Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pretty-print, pysnmp

I'm new to python and looking for some assistance on formatting print output to rows and columns. This data will eventually be sent to csv file.

The script will grab data from multiple hosts. The number of lines is variable as well as the length of the interface name and description.

Currently the output looks like this:

```
hostname IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 = GigabitEthernet0/0/0<br/>
hostname IF-MIB::ifAlias.1 = --> InterfaceDesc<br/>
hostname IF-MIB::ifOperStatus.1 = 'up'<br/>
hostname IF-MIB::ifDescr.2 = GigabitEthernet0/0/1<br/>
hostname IF-MIB::ifAlias.2 = --> InterfaceDesc<br/>
hostname IF-MIB::ifOperStatus.2 = 'up'<br/>
hostname IF-MIB::ifDescr.3 = GigabitEthernet0/0/2<br/>
hostname IF-MIB::ifAlias.3 = --> InterfaceDesc<br/>
hostname IF-MIB::ifOperStatus.3 = 'up'<br/>
```

I'm trying to format it to the following rows and columns with headers of each row(hostname, interface, interface desc, and status).

```
hostname        interface              interface desc       status
hostname        GigabitEthernet0/0/0   InterfaceDesc        up
hostname        GigabitEthernet0/0/1   InterfaceDesc        up
hostname        GigabitEthernet0/0/2   InterfaceDesc        up
```

The print code I currently have is here. I want to keep the print statements for errors.

```
for errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds in snmp_iter:
            # Check for errors and print out results
            if errorIndication:
                print(errorIndication)
            elif errorStatus:
                print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                                errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
            else:
                for varBind in varBinds:
                    print(hostip),
                    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

Full script:

```
from pysnmp.hlapi import *

routers = ["router1"]

#adds routers to bulkCmd
def snmpquery (hostip):
    snmp_iter = bulkCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                        CommunityData('Community'),
                        UdpTransportTarget((hostip, 161)),
                        ContextData(),
                        0, 50,  # fetch up to 50 OIDs 
                        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifDescr')),
                        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifAlias')),
                        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifOperStatus')),
                        lexicographicMode=False) # End bulk request once outside of OID child objects
    for errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds in snmp_iter:
        # Check for errors and print out results
        if errorIndication:
            print(errorIndication)
        elif errorStatus:
            print('%s at %s' % (errorStatus.prettyPrint(),
                            errorIndex and varBinds[int(errorIndex) - 1][0] or '?'))
        else:
            for rowId, varBind in enumerate(varBindTable):
                oid, value = varBind
                print('%20.20s' % value)
                if not rowId and rowId % 3 == 0:
                    print('\n')

# calls snmpquery for all routers in list
for router in routers:
    snmpquery(router)
```

Any help you can provide is much appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the `snmp_iter` is initialized with three SNMP table columns:

```
snmp_iter = bulkCmd(SnmpEngine(),
                    UsmUserData('usr-md5-des', 'authkey1', 'privkey1'),
                    Udp6TransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
                    ContextData(),
                    0, 25,
                    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifDescr')),
                    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifAlias')),
                    ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('IF-MIB', 'ifOperStatus')))
```

you can be sure that (for the *GETNEXT* and *GETBULK* commands) pysnmp always returns rectangular table in a row by row fashion.

Knowing the number of the columns you have requested (3) you should be able to print the output row by row:

```
for rowId, varBind in enumerate(varBindTable):
    oid, value = varBind
    print('%20.20s' % value)
    if not rowId and rowId % 3 == 0:
        print('\n')
```

Comment: Thanks IIya, should I define varBindTable and assign it a value of varBinds?

Comment: Hit send to soon. Yes     snmp_inter is intialized with three SNMP tables. I've added full script